# After Reading a *.lst file(multiple lines with different filenames along with its path),How to find specific filename with its path in CMAKE?

Tags: cmake

Lets Consider a lst file "txt_filelist.lst" which has different text files mentioned with different path's, Now After reading the "txt_filelist.lst" file how to identify a specific text file along with its path in CMAKE?

**txt_filelist.lst File:**

```
`variants\EXX\application\a2l\srcxx_xx_xx\xx_xx_xx.txt`
`variants\EXX\application\a2l\srcxx_xx_xx\xx_xx_xx.txt`
`variants\EXX\application\a2l\srcxx_xx_xx\xx_xx_xx.txt`
`variants\EXX\application\a2l\srcxx_xx_xx\xx_xx_xx.txt`
```

After reading the lst file `txt_filelist.lst` How can I first identify the `srcxx_xx_xx.txt` in the lst and then secondly How can I fetch its entire path as `variants\EXX\application\a2l\srcxx_xx_xx\xx_xx_xx.txt` in CMAKE?

Thanks in Advance..!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`file(STRINGS)`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/file.html#strings) to read the lines of the file to a list variable. `get_filename_component` can be used to separate file names according to your needs. Using `file(TO_NATIVE_PATH)` may be necessary, if you use `get_filename_component` in a way that yields a path containing separators, but most tools should be able to work with forward slashes, even on Windows:

```
file(STRINGS txt_filelist.lst FILE_LINES LENGTH_MINIMUM 1)

message("=========================")
foreach(LINE IN LISTS FILE_LINES)
    get_filename_component(FILE_NAME "${LINE}" NAME)
    get_filename_component(FILE_DIR "${LINE}" DIRECTORY)
    file(TO_NATIVE_PATH "${LINE}" FILE_PATH_NATIVE)
    message(
"------------------------
LINE             = '${LINE}'
FILE_NAME        = '${FILE_NAME}'   
FILE_DIR         = '${FILE_DIR}'    
FILE_PATH_NATIVE = '${FILE_PATH_NATIVE}'    
"
    )
endforeach()
message("=========================")
```

Note: The `LENGTH_MINIMUM 1` option is there to ignore empty lines. This may not be necessary depending on the input you get.